# WCF DataService with multiple entity models

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have two different entity models (ie, 2 edmx files).I need to access these two models via wcf data service .If one edmx its possible tom connect through the following lined.

```
public class WcfDataService : ODataService<testEntities> // testEntities is my enity
```

How can I add multiple entities in this service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411474/wcf-ria-services-loading-multiple-entities

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1918684/5441383.aspx/1?WCF+DataService+with+multiple+entity+models